# Clear errors in angularjs forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form field that is required and email type. I want the form validation work when I lose focus from my field, so I am using:  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"

example:

```
<input class="sng-size-input" type="email" required
                            ng-keyup="clearValidation(emailform.email_interface_form,emailform.email_interface_form.fromAddress)"
                            ng-model="emailSelectedValue.fromAddress" name="fromAddress"
                            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                            value="{{emailSelectedValue.fromAddress}}"
                            ng-disabled="!emailSelectedValue.enabled" id="emailFromAddress">
                            <span class="sng_form_error"
                            ng-show="emailform.email_interface_form.fromAddress.$error.email"
                            data-i18n="Not Valid e-mail"> </span> <span
                            class="sng_form_error"
                            ng-show="emailform.email_interface_form.fromAddress.$error.required"
                            data-i18n="Required"></span>
```

when back to the field and start typing again I want my errors messages to disappear, so I am using:

$rootScope.clearValidation = function(form,field){
      field.$setPristine(true);

};

my red css on the field disappears, but the error messages are not.
What am I missing?

my css:

```
.form-validation .ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border-color: #e94b3b;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because in that time your input has errors and your ng-show expression returning true, you can use 
`$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid);` to set this input back to valid for more check [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: I have added to clearValidation  this: form.$setValidity("fromAddress",true); and it still not working

Comment: my mistake.... I changed to field.$setValidity("email",true); and this works. Thanks,

Comment: there is one issue with required state... once I change to field.$setValidity("required",true); when come back to empy field with required, then add some text and remove it again I don't get required error note. is there away to handle it?

Comment: you should .$setValidity("required",true); only in that case when your input value is not empty you can check it with $viewValue

Comment: I tried it and for some reason it still don't work. it looks like it remembers the last time I changed the validity to true.